# How to trigger a show or hide operation based on div size when the browser is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am designing a summary container for the author page in a book publishing website. Some authors have more summary content while others have less content. I want to enable/ disable show more/less button dynamically when the height of the div container crosses a cutoff height(180px). So, it turns out to control the height of the div container dynamically (180px and original height). I need a piece of code which works perfectly in all browsers.

I have got a code implemented here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rraagghhu/9dgs6432/3/

HTML :

```
<div class = "container">
<div class="info-wrapper">
<div class="info">
Chetan Bhagat is the author of six blockbuster books.These include five novels—Five Point Someone (2004), One Night @ the Call Center (2005), The 3 Mistakes of My Life (2008), 2 States (2009), 
Revolution 2020 (2011), the non-fiction title What Young India Wants (2012) and Half Girlfriend (2014). Chetan’s books have remained bestsellers since their release. 
Four out his five novels have been already adapted into successful Bollywood films and the others are in process of being adapted as well. The New York Times called him the ‘the biggest selling English language novelist in India’s history’. Time magazine named him amongst the ‘100 most influential people in the world’ and Fast Company, USA, listed him as one of the world’s ‘100 most creative people in business’. Chetan writes columns for leading English and Hindi newspapers, focusing on youth and national development issues. He is also a motivational speaker and screenplay writer. Chetan quit his international investment banking career in 2009 to devote his entire time to writing and make change happen in the country. He lives in Mumbai with his wife, Anusha, an ex-classmate from IIM-A, and his twin boys, Shyam and Ishaan. You can email him at info@chetanbhagat.com or fill in the Guestbook with your feedback. You can also follow him on twitter (@chetan_bhagat) or like his Facebook fanpage (https://www.facebook.com/chetanbhagat.fanpage).
</div>
<a href="#" class="more">(more)</a>
<a href="#" class="less">(less)</a>
</div>

<div class = "footer"> THIS IS FOOTER </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    background-color: yellow;
 }
.footer{
    background-color: yellow;
 }
 .info-wrapper {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 0 2.5em 0; 
    background-color: red;
 } 
 .info {

    max-height: 180px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative; 
    text-align: justify;
}
.info:after, .aftershadow {
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.info-wrapper a {
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    font: 700 .67em/1.25em Arial;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.less { height: auto; display: none; }
.more { display: none; }
```

Jquery:

```
if($(".info")[0].scrollHeight > $(".info").height()) {
        $("a.more").show();
    }

    $("a.more").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".info").css({"overflow": "visible"});
        $("a.less").show();
        $("a.more").hide();
        return false;
    });

    $("a.less").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".info").css({"overflow": "hidden"});
        $("a.more").show();
        $("a.less").hide();
        return false;
    });
```

As you can see, the footer stays at the absolute position. If the more button is clicked, the (less) should come down, below that should come the footer. Is it possible to enable/disable the show more/less button dynamically when the browser is shrunk/expanded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `max-height` to `100%` for show more and set the `max-height` to `180px` when show less.

**[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahdaen/9dgs6432/14/)**

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. Now, I request you to do the following.

1. Go to the updated JSFiddle link you have given above. 
2. Expand the Result screen as wide as possible.
3. Run the script.
4. Now, shrink the Result screen.

You can see that some text at the end goes missing as you shrink closer and closer. This is because you're resizing the screen width on the runtime. Is it possible to write a code to solve this problem too? Thank you for helping me out. :-)

Comment: Do you mean want to hide the `show more` button when the `info` height less than `180px` and show then button when `info` height more than `180px` when resizing window?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `overflow` to ever be shown, instead just increase the `max-height` to 100%.

```
$("a.more").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".info").css({"max-height": "100%"});
    $("a.less").show();
    $("a.more").hide();
    return false;
});
```

I also added in some padding so you can see the text a bit easier.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dgs6432/8/)

This is really another question, but using `innerHeight` instead of `height` you can detect if the text is overflowing with the padding on window resize:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(".info")[0].scrollHeight > $(".info").innerHeight()) {
        $("a.more").show();
    }
});
```

I also positioned the less/more button absolutely at the bottom of the info box to overlay any text that might extend into the padding:

```
.info-wrapper a {
        left: 0; bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: red;
        position: absolute;
        font: 700 .67em/1.25em Arial;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: underline;
        cursor: pointer;
        line-height: 20px;
}
```

Full code is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dgs6432/25/)

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. Now, I request you to do the following.

1. Go to the updated JSFiddle link you have given above. 
2. Expand the Result screen as wide as possible.
3. Run the script.
4. Now, shrink the Result screen.

You can see that some text at the end goes missing as you shrink closer and closer. This is because you're resizing the screen width on the runtime. Is it possible to write a code to solve this problem too? Thank you for helping me out. :-)

Comment: I don't see any text going missing in my solution. When you shrink the screen after expanding, it wraps the text and expands the red box.

Comment: Have a look at this Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rraagghhu/9dgs6432/21/

In this case, the show more/less button must be disabled.It should be active only when the height of the div exceeds 180px, and automatically disappear when it is less than 180px.

Answer (score 1):

You are not removing the max-height from the CSS and that is what is causing the issue. You can do two things here:

1. Either you can set the `max-height` to `100%`
2. or, you can set the `max-height` in another css class and add and remove that class to the info div dynamically

Create a css style:

```
.restrict{
    max-height: 180px;
}
```

On click of more:

```
$(".info").removeClass('restrict');
```

On click of less:

```
$(".info").addClass('restrict');
```

See my forked fiddle with the changes:

https://jsfiddle.net/jdnf5vka/4/

Comment: Yeah, I saw the fiddle. As you expand the Result window, as the whole text is accommodated into the div container, you can see that the show more button is not disappearing. And I request you to do the following steps,
1. Go to the updated JSFiddle link you have given above. 
2. Expand the Result screen as wide as possible. 
3. Run the script. 
4. Now, shrink the Result screen. 

You can see that some text at the end goes missing as you shrink closer and closer.

Comment: That is a different issue. To overcome that you need to provide a padding. Moreover, if you shrink the results window to anything less than that of your content, first it tries to accomodate the text by putting linebreaks instead of whitespace. If there are no whitespace to be removed then the content will obviously get clipped or appear on top of other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can enable and disable the buttons as the browser is resized.

You'll need to build your javascript like this:

```
// make your function re-usable
var buttonChecker = function() {
    // show / hide buttons logic here
}

// bind the function to the resize event (note, no parenthesis for calling the function here, it's just a reference passed in that is then called when the resize event is triggered)
$(window).on('resize', buttonChecker);

// call your function on page load so the buttons are correctly shown then (note, parenthesis are used, function is called
buttonChecker();
```

This way when the browser is resized the show / hide button functionality will be re-called.

PS - here is the OPs example fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/9dgs6432/20/ - note the contents of the `buttonChecker()` function and the logic to hide as well as show.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the code. I have implemented over here

http://jsfiddle.net/rraagghhu/9dgs6432/12/

But it works only when the show more/less button appears for the first time. And, it does't disappear when the screen size is expanded to its most. I will make my question clear by asking you to do the following :
1. Shrink the Result Screen 2. Run the script 3. Now, expand the result window. Even if the text is accommodated in the div, still the show more button appears. Is there any way you can make it visible/invisible? Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: yeah it think your going to have to add your button show logic into the function, so that it can be called on `resize` - you can see my example, the function is empty, so you'll need to fill it :-) see this ... fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/9dgs6432/20/ - note how I filled the function with the logic and also added stuff to hide as well as show

Comment: Thank you, Toni Leigh! This piece of code works perfect! :-)